# OpenMP implementation increasingly slow with thread count increase

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been trying to learn to use OpenMP. However my code seemed to be running more quickly in series that parallel.

Indeed the more threads used, the slower the computation time.

To illustrate this I ran an experiment. I am trying to do the following operation:

```
long int C[num], D[num];
for (i=0; i<num; i++) C[i] = i;
for (i=0; i<num; i++){
    for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
        D[i] = pm(C[i]);
    }
 }
```

where the function pm is simply

```
int pm(int val) {
    val++;
    val--;
    return val;
}
```

I implemented the inner loop in parallel and compared the run times as a function of the number of iterations on the inner loop (N) and the number of threads used. The code for the experiment is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "omp.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

static long num = 1000;
using namespace std;

int pm(int val) {
    val++;
    val--;
    return val;
}

int main() {

    int i, j, k, l;
    int iter = 8;
    int iterT = 4;
    long inum[iter];
    for (i=0; i<iter; i++) inum[i] = pow(10, i); 

    double serial[iter][iterT], parallel[iter][iterT];

    ofstream outdata;
    outdata.open("output.dat");
    if (!outdata) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    """Experiment Start"""
    for (l=1; l<iterT+1; l++) {
        for (k=0; k<iter; k++) {
            clock_t start = clock();
            long int A[num], B[num];
            omp_set_num_threads(l);
            for (i=0; i<num; i++) A[i] = i;
            for (i=0; i<num; i++){
                #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
                for (j=0; j<inum[k]; j++) {
                    B[i] = pm(A[i]);
                }
            }  
            clock_t finish = clock();
            parallel[k][l-1] = (double) (finish - start) /\ 
            CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;

            start =   clock();
            long int C[num], D[num];
            for (i=0; i<num; i++) C[i] = i;
            for (i=0; i<num; i++){
                for (j=0; j<inum[k]; j++) {
                    D[i] = pm(C[i]);
                }
            }
            finish = clock();
            serial[k][l-1] = (double) (finish - start) /\ 
            CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        }
    }
    """Experiment End"""


    for (j=0; j<iterT; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<iter; i++) {
            outdata << inum[i] << " " << j + 1 << " " << serial[i][j]\
            << " " << parallel[i][j]<< std::endl;
        }
    }
    outdata.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The link below is a plot of log(T) against log(N) for each thread count.

[A plot of the run times for varying number of threads and magnitude of computational task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLhYT.png)

(I just noticed that the legend labels for serial and parallel are the wrong way around).

As you can see using more than one thread increases the time greatly. Adding more threads increases the time taken linearly as a function of number of threads.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: The `B` array is never used except for the inner `for` loop. Thus the code is equivalent to each thread doing nothing, right? Which might be optimized like that by the compiler. Essentially you only pay the cost of creating and destroying threads. Try compiling with disabled optimizations to see if that's the case.

Comment: I thought that, despite the `B` array only being used in the inner `for` loop, the threads were still operating the function `pm` on the `A` array. Hence the threads 'work' comes from there. I could have made it simpler, but I wanted to loosely simulate the kind of task I actuality want to perform. However once I get back to my machine I will do as you suggested.

Comment: The `pm` function again does nothing so the compiler may remove it entirely. You may want to return `rand()` in `pm`. The compiler cant optimize that because theres a syscall under the hood.

Comment: I have tried both changing the `pm` function to return `rand()` and disabling compiler optimisations, and both together. It still behaves as before. (Thanks for your help, by the way.)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. That may be a stupid question but do you actually have multiple cpu cores? :) Note that for cpu bound tasks going with the number of threads over the number of cores won't increase performance, just the opposite.

Comment: Yes indeed, printing the output of the `function omp_get_thread_num()` in the parallel loop returns all four of the available cores.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what you mean by your last edit? About the number of threads over the number of cores?

Comment: If you have X cores (or physical threads including cpu's hyper threading tech) then your cpu can do at most X calculations in parallel. Now application threads are some abstracts assigned to each physical core by the OS. So if you have Y threads with Y <= X then your cpu can run those threads in parallel. But if Y > X then the OS have to suspend some threads to allow others to run. Also known as the context switch. So with Y > X you don't get any performance boost, you only loose it due to the context switch (the cost scales with the number of threads).

Comment: Also note that other running processes on your machine affect this.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, the code above sets the number of threads to use for each test via the `omp_set_num_threads()` function. The number of threads is increased from 1 to 4 for each test, where 4 is the max number of cores available. Thanks again for the help! I'll run the code on the dedicated cluster with 30 cores tomorrow and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Freakish above was correct about the pm() function doing nothing, and the compiler was getting confused.

It also turns out that the rand() function does not play well withing OpenMP for loops.

Adding the function sqrt(i) (i being the loop index) I achieved the expected speedup to my code.